# What file systems does Windows 2008 support?

Tags: filesystems, windows-server-2008

I'm doing a schoolwork assignment and I'm currently on the question:
"What file systems does Windows 2008 support?"

Sounds easy but I dunno if it's a trap. It would be easy to say FAT32, NTFS etc. but I tried to google like an idiot but couldn't find a concrete answer. I'm sure it supports NTFS but what about FAT?
I also read about DFS and NTFS5, what is that?

Comment: IT'S A TRAP!!!!

Comment: @Charkel: **please** do not cross-post, we can migrate questions anywhere.  It looks like your question was off-topic at SF...

Comment: Please clarify whether "supports" means "installs to" or "reads/writes to".

Comment: Good point. In might install to NTFS and maybe FAT, but it also reads iso9660, UDF and you can install additional drivers for HFS or ext2. (and probably more).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NTFS4,](http://www.certiguide.com/apfr/cg_apfr_NTFSv4.htm) [& 5](http://www.certiguide.com/apfr/cg_apfr_NTFSv5.htm), [exFAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT), [FAT32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32), [FAT16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#Final_FAT16), [FAT or FAT12](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT12)

[Source of information](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs_vs_fat.htm)

NTFS.com does not list FAT32 or exFAT for 2008, but this is wrong [according to Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140365)

and don't forget [HPFS](http://www.certiguide.com/apfr/cg_apfr_HPFS.htm),

I have always assumed any windows version supports all previous file systems but can find no documentation to support this assumption.

This list does not include some removable media formats.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it supports NTFS, FAT32, FAT, and exFAT. (I don't know if they consider DFS a file system but it supports that too.)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that windows also supports UDF.

you must use the command line as far as i know see below
format d: /fs:udf

i agree with Moab about assuming any windows version supports all previous file systems.

Comment: Windows also has Installable File System http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installable_File_System